# InitializeComponent generated code formatting in

Tags: vb.net, winforms, designer

Is there a way to define how the code is generated in the InitializeComponent Method ?

For instance, when saving a modified form from the designer, it happens that it has true instead of True, and has "SuspendLayout()" instead of "SuspendLayout"

This is quite annoying as when merging the code, it causes lots of issues, and it is difficult to identify what has really changed.

Comment: That is [technically possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx).  The only real advantage I can think of is that you  won't be merging code for a while when you pursue this.

Comment: Using SVN and WinForms for ages, I never had any of your "lots of issues". What are these issues?

Comment: Why would you want to omit the parentheses when calling `SuspendLayout`?  I've always disliked that aspect of VB.

Comment: @UweKeim When two users make design changes to a Control, the result is usually completely unmergable. We call around the office to obtain an "exclusive lock" if two people are working on the same control.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I don't. The Winforms designer generate codes without the parentheses.

Comment: @UweKeim : issues are that if a change a control width for instance, all lines are changed (reformatted) and it is difficult to see what has really be changed. Problem is probably that developpers have different pretty printing configuration on their laptop.